# Bootstrap 4 beta 3 throws error with angular-cli

Tags: angular-cli, bootstrap-4

I am getting below error while updating my bootstrap package to 4.0.0-beta.3. Let me know if I am missing anything. It was working with beta.2

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/common": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/core": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/forms": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/http": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/router": "^5.1.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/language-service": "^5.1.2",
```

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss
>   Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
>       at error (E:*********\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
>       at Function.browserslist.checkName (E:*********\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
>       at Function.select (E:*********\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
>       at E:*********\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at browserslist (E:*********\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
>       at Browsers.parse (E:*********\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:44:14)
>       at new Browsers (E:*********\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:39:28)
>       at loadPrefixes (E:*********\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:56:18)
>       at plugin (E:*********\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:62:18)
>       at LazyResult.run (E:*********\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:270:20)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (E:*********\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:185:32)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (E:*********\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:197:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (E:*********\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:197:22)
>       at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (E:*********\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:224:20)
>       at new Promise ()  @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss 4:14-164  @ multi
>   ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss
>   ./node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss
>   ./node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css
>   ./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css
>   ./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css
>   ./node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css
>   ./node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css
>   ./node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css
>   ./src/styles.scss

Comment: Seems like a known problem https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020.
For a quick fix i have copied latest autoprefixer 7.2.3 folder to node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modul. This fixed the problem

Comment: after copying autoprefixer latest folder it worked. but when I run ng build --prod command, its again giving the same error. Any fix for this?

Comment: For Bootstrap 4.0.0 (release) I just have upgraded the CLI to 1.6.5 — and it works!

Answer (score 15):

You can use Bootstrap 4 beta 3, but first edit bootstrap.json/package.json in node_modules/bootstrap:

> "browserslist": [
>       "last 1 major version", <----- **delete this line**
>       ">= 1%", <----- **delete this line**
>       "Chrome >= 45",
>       "Firefox >= 38",
>       "Edge >= 12",
>       "Explorer >= 10",
>       "iOS >= 9",
>       "Safari >= 9",
>       "Android >= 4.4",
>       "Opera >= 30"
>       ],

It looks like the *last n major versions* syntax was added in *browserList 2.4* and *autoprefixer* updated to *version 2 of browserList in version 7.0*.

So, any version of autoprefixer above 7.0 should work.

Updating the autoprefixer should also do the job for you.

Comment: I tried the same and it worked with angular CLI 1.5.2, but upgrading the autoprefixer solution didn't work for me!

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by an [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020) of angular-cli , the temp fix is

- Do not reference bootstrap's css/scss in `.angular-cli.json`,
- Import bootstrap's scss file in the `style.scss` file of your app like this:

  ```
  scss
  @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
  ```

for more details, please look at my [ng-seed](https://github.com/beginor/ng-seed) repo.

Comment: Yes @zhimin I did the same. but still, prod build is throwing the error.
did it not give any error on ng build --prod to you?

Comment: thanks! i tried to be slick and let angular-cli.json bring it in... went back to the original @import and it worked again...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using angular, but faced with the same issue with bootstrap v."4.0.0":

`import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";`

Adding `"autoprefixer": "^7.2.5"` to my package.json worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded to Angular CLI 1.7.x and it started working fine. I recommend this solution. I mean upgrading the Angular CLI and it should work for you!

@Yashwanth M solution should work in the worst case scenario!